# iOS Sample Code - Lister (Cannot compile)

Tags: ios, iphone, sample

Could someone experienced with iOS applications please try and help me get the Lister Sample Code up and running on my iPhone and iPad (Swift version)?

Source Code available here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html

I've been trying to follow the instructions in the ReadMe but I just cannot get it to compile or upload.

Could someone please, download it and see for yourselves?

After replacing everything mentioned in the Read Me I just keep getting:
"This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique".

Thank you.

Comment: If you changed all bundle IDs, try a project clean.

Comment: Hi,
I tried many Cleans earlier but still no joy.
I'd really like someone to try and see if it's just me.

Comment: my firs attempt failed with a different issue.  LOL.  I will try again.

Comment: I think I followed the instructions exactly and carefully and I can't get it to compile either, but with a different diagnostic. I'm giving up on it after many tries. Lister is cited in one of the WWDC-15 sessions as a sample app for demonstrating UITesting but in my opinion it's a poor choice. It has way too many moving parts to consider it a good UITesting demo. I find the same problem with most of Apple's "demo" projects. They don't demonstrate one technology in isolation in a simplistic way so it's quick to understand. Instead they try to be a fully useful app.